# sed removing lines from a range that have a pattern, if the range contains another pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How do I remove certain lines containing a pattern, from a range, ONLY if the range contains a second pattern?

For example:

```
## start
  ## first line
    ## 2nd pattern
      ## third line
# end
```

The range is from `## start` to `# end`, but I only want to remove lines with `##` in them.

I used the command `sed "/## start/,/# end/ {/##/ d}` to do that.

The problem comes in when I only want to delete these lines when `2nd pattern` is present in those lines. Thus

```
## start
  ## first line
    ## second line
# end
```

should not be deleted. However, it will be deleted with the command I have.

There can be multiple lines with `##` (Not just the 4 levels I have shown), but they will always be together.

Edit:

```
## start
  ## first line
    ## adsg
      ## third line
# end
## start
  ## first line
    ## 2nd pattern
      ## second line
# end
```

should give

```
## start
  ## first line
    ## adsg
      ## third line
# end
# end
```

Comment: Your sample input isn't adequate to test your requirements. Just doing `grep -v '2nd'` would convert your input to your output without actually doing what you want. Come up with an example that actually demonstrates your required behavior and no other behavior so we have something to test against. Also check that your output can be produced from your input - currently it cant, looks like a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this script `replace.awk`:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{f=0; inblock=0}
/## start/{inblock=1}
inblock && /# end/{
    if(!f){
        for (k in m){
            mm[k] = m[k];
        }
    }
    for (k in m){
        delete m[k];
    }
    inblock = 0; 
}
inblock{m[NR]=$0;}
!inblock{mm[NR]=$0;}
inblock && /## 2nd pattern/ {f = 1;} 
END{ 
    for (k in mm){
        print mm[k]
    }
}
```

Obviously you need to give permission to execute, `chmod +x replace.awk`

Finnally, to run the script, use: `./replace.awk file`

Comment: Is there a way to make it go through the entire file rather than specify the end each time? I would like it to be as automated as possible

Comment: It also deletes text between ## start and #end even if `2nd pattern` is not present for that block, if there is `2nd pattern` between ## start and #end somewhere in the file

Comment: Can you give the case when that happens ?, also can you explain me in more detail, your first comment?

Comment: So, in that case, there are two ranges?

Comment: Just the entire file

Comment: The question was unclear. I just changed the answer according that new information. Can you specify more your other question: "is there a way to make it go through the entire file rather than specify the end each time?" ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `2nd` pattern to your delete expression, e.g.

```
$ sed '/## start/,/# end/{/##.*2nd/d}' file
## start
  ## first line
      ## third line
# end
```

You can add the full `'2nd\ pattern'` to further specify that exact phrase if there is the possibility there are other lines with `2nd` in them you want to keep.

If I misunderstood, please drop a comment below.

Comment: Yes i know how to do that. It's just that I want other lines with ## preceding to be deleted as well, but ONLY if `2nd pattern` is within the block. I edited the question to include a clearer example

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^## start/{:a;N;/^# end/M!ba;/2nd pattern/!b;s/^.*##.*\n//Mg}' file
```

This gathers up lines between `## start` and `# end` and bails out unless the collection contains the second pattern. If a match is made the lines in the collection that contain `##` are removed.

N.B. The `M` flag allows for multiline regexps. In these cases the metacharacter `^` and `$` act as markers for the beginning and ending of lines.